# Using processing instructions to set a variable in XSLT

Tags: xslt, docbook

I'm using asciidoc with the docbook backend, and I'm trying to pass a URL as a variable from asciidoc through to docbook, where the variable can have different values throughout the document.  For instance, I want my users to be able to do something like:

```
# url="http://foo/

== some text

Some para....

# url="http://bar/

== some text

Some para....
```

My idea was to use pass through blocks to add processing instructions which could be picked up in docbook, eg:

```
pass::[<?my_url http://foo ?>]
== some title

some para...
```

What I can't figure out how to do is to write the XSLT which expresses the following: "find the previous processing-instruction called `my_url` and use its contents to set the value of a variable"

Following the guidance given in http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ProcessingInstructions.html I tried using a `dbhtml` PI, eg:

```
<?dbhtml my_url="http://foo.com" ?>
```

and in my XSL:

```
  <xsl:template match="ulink[@role='edit_me']">
    <xsl:variable name="my_url">  
      <xsl:call-template name="dbhtml-attribute">  
        <xsl:with-param name="pis"  
             select="ancestor-or-self::entry/processing-instruction('dbhtml')"/>  
        <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="'my_url'"/>  
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    GOT: <xsl:value-of select="$my_url" />
  </xsl:template>
```

But I'm completely unable to retrieve the value I'm after.  Help gratefully appreciated.

### Added example XML

For instance, take this example XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">

<book lang="en">
<bookinfo>
    <title>Title one</title>
</bookinfo>

<?my_url http://foo.com ?>

<preface>
    <title><ulink role="edit_me" url="test.asciidoc">Edit me</ulink></title>
</preface>

<?my_url http://bar.com ?>

<chapter id="_title_two">
    <title>Title two<ulink role="edit_me" url="test.asciidoc">Edit me</ulink></title>
    <simpara>Some text</simpara>
</chapter>

<chapter id="_title_three">
    <title>Title three<ulink role="edit_me" url="test.asciidoc">Edit me</ulink></title>
    <simpara>More text</simpara>
</chapter>

</book>
```

I want to render each of the `edit_me` links using the URL specified in the preceding `my_url` processing instruction.  So the first link will use `foo.com`, while the next two will use `bar.com`.

Comment: "dbhtl-attribute" looks like a typo. There is a template called "dbhtml-attribute" in pi.xsl in DocBook-XSL. Did you mean to call that template?

Comment: yeah, it was a typo in the question, but was correct in my (failing) code. i've corrected it, thanks

Comment: Example docbook XML to match your example would be helpful. It is difficult to determine from your pseudocode describing the XML structure why your template is not producing the correct output.

Comment: @MadsHansen I've added a concrete example, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using:

```
select="ancestor-or-self::entry/processing-instruction('dbhtml')"
```

but there is no `entry` in your example, and all the processing instructions are children  of the root `book` element.

It sounds like you really want to grab the value of the closest *preceding* processing instruction. For example, applying:

```
<xsl:template match="ulink[@role='edit_me']">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="url">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding::processing-instruction('my_url')[1]"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(along with the identity transform template and a template to suppress processing-instructions) would result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book lang="en">
   <bookinfo>
      <title>Title one</title>
   </bookinfo>
   <preface>
      <title>
         <ulink url="http://foo.com "/>
      </title>
   </preface>
   <chapter id="_title_two">
      <title>Title two<ulink url="http://bar.com "/>
      </title>
      <simpara>Some text</simpara>
   </chapter>
   <chapter id="_title_three">
      <title>Title three<ulink url="http://bar.com "/>
      </title>
      <simpara>More text</simpara>
   </chapter>
</book>
```

Comment: awesome, thank you.  my use of "entry" reflects the perils of copy-and-paste programming

Answer (score 1):

**This short and complete transformation uses and overrides the identity rule**.

**Do note** that no `<xsl:attribute>` is used (it is really unnecessary):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ulink[. = 'Edit me']">
    <ulink role="{@role}" url="{preceding::processing-instruction('my_url')[1]}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ulink>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<book lang="en">
    <bookinfo>
        <title>Title one</title>
    </bookinfo>
    <?my_url http://foo.com ?>
    <preface>
        <title>
            <ulink role="edit_me" url="test.asciidoc">Edit me</ulink>
        </title>
    </preface>
    <?my_url http://bar.com ?>
    <chapter id="_title_two">
        <title>Title two
            <ulink role="edit_me" url="test.asciidoc">Edit me</ulink>
        </title>
        <simpara>Some text</simpara>
    </chapter>
    <chapter id="_title_three">
        <title>Title three
            <ulink role="edit_me" url="test.asciidoc">Edit me</ulink>
        </title>
        <simpara>More text</simpara>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<book lang="en">
    <bookinfo>
        <title>Title one</title>
    </bookinfo>

    <preface>
        <title>
            <ulink role="edit_me" url="http://foo.com ">Edit me</ulink>
        </title>
    </preface>

    <chapter id="_title_two">
        <title>Title two
            <ulink role="edit_me" url="http://bar.com ">Edit me</ulink>
        </title>
        <simpara>Some text</simpara>
    </chapter>
    <chapter id="_title_three">
        <title>Title three
            <ulink role="edit_me" url="http://bar.com ">Edit me</ulink>
        </title>
        <simpara>More text</simpara>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

Comment: thanks @dimitre.  good solution.  i actually needed to store the custom URL in a variable so that I could use it in a `xsl:choose` clause later on.